# Is it possible to control Service Fabric hosted service restart behaviour?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I can't find much documentation on the action that Service Fabric takes when a service it is hosting fails.  I have performed some experimentation (using a stateless service in a local cluster), the results of which are below.  My question is: is it possible to change this behaviour?

There are two distinct scenarios that I tested.

1. An exception thrown from the RunAsync() method.
   The hosted service is restarted immediately on another cluster node.  If no other node is available then it is restarted on the same node.  There does not appear to be any limit to the number of times the restart will be attempted or any kind of back-off in terms of the interval between attempts.
2. The hosted service fails to start (e.g. an exception is thrown before RunAsync() is called).
   The hosted service is restarted on the same node.  In my test environment there appears to be a fixed interval between restart attempts (15 seconds) but no limit to the number of attempts.

I can see in the cluster configuration that there are some parameters in the Hosting section that look like they might be relevant (ActivationMaxRetryInterval, ActivationRetryBackoffInterval, ActivationMaxFailureCount) and I am guessing that these cover scenario (2) above (assuming that Activation == service start).  These affect the entire cluster by the looks of it.

Comment: did you see this?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings

Comment: @LoekD Yes and it details the Activation... settings that I mentioned in the question.  I am actually more interested in any settings that could help with point (1), though.  Thanks anyway.